# What are the probabilities of these events?

Tags: probability

Grant Funding Suppose a group of research proposals was evaluated by a panel of experts to decide whether or not they were worthy of funding. When these same proposals were submitted to a second independent panel of experts, the decision to fund was reversed in 30% of the cases. If the probability that a proposal is judged worthy of funding by the first panel is .2, what are the probabilities of these events?

```
a. A worthy proposal is approved by both panels.

b. A worthy proposal is disapproved by both panels.

c. A worthy proposal is approved by one panel.
```

I can get the first one, but I really don't know what to do after the first question.

$A$ = approved by group one 
$A^{c}$ = not approved by group one 
$B$ = approved by group two 
$B^c$ = not approved by group two

$P(A) = 0.2$ 
$P(A^c) = 0.8$ 
$P(B^c|A) = 0.3$ 
$P(B|A) = 0.7$

For question part a, we have $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A) = 0.2 \times 0.7 = 0.14$

For question part b, the answer is 0.56, but I really don't know how they get this. Not sure if i'm interpreting this question right.

I can see that $0.7 \times 0.8$ comes to 0.56 however I don't think I know the relationships between these probabilities to see how we would multiply these two numbers together. $P(A^c) \times P(B|A)$ just is not making sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

For part B, for both panels to disapprove, you would need the $0.8$ probability of the first one disapproving AND the $0.7$ probability that the decision isn’t reversed in the second panel, so you would multiply them to get $0.56$.

For part C, it would be $8.4$%, because either the first panel approves and the second disapproves, so $(0.2)(0.3)=0.06$, or the first disapproves and the second approves, so $(0.8)(0.3)=0.024$. You would add these to get $0.084$.

Comment: The answer for part c is 0.3. I can see what you have done now though, which is not how I read it. You are reading that the decision of the first group is reversed 30% of the time by the second group. Where I read it as only approval decisions are reversed 30% of the time. Maybe I was interpreting the question wrongly. Anyway, you did the hard part @MathAndPhysics . If you could fix up your arithmetic for part c you will get 0.3 and then I will tick it off.